# Firm level data with many zeros

Tags: regression, zero-inflation

I'm working with some firm-level (cross-sec.) data where a substantial no. of firms (about 15%) report zero revenue for the given year. 
The rest of the data is fine (in fact normally distributed)

How do I deal with this? Any suggestion(s) please.

Comment: What do you want to do with the data?

Comment: I want to run a regression. This is my dependent variable.